# Multiple Versions of SQL Server using Entity Framework in a single ASP.NET application

Tags: sql-server-2005, entity-framework, sql-server-2000, entity

I am using the Entity Framework in a web application that utilizes SQL server 2000, 2005, and 2008. When I create a new EDMX file using anything other than 2008 (version of the first edmx created) I receive `error 0172: All SSDL artifacts must target the same provider. The Provider 'MyDatabase' is different from ' MyDatabase ' that was encountered earlier.` It seems that somewhere in the code the connection is wired to a 2008 datastore and when it checks the SSDL file and sees a different ProviderManifestToken value it throws this error. I am a little more than frustrated. It is hard to imagine that EF will only work with a single version of Sql Server per application. I am fairly sure there must be a setting or workaround. Does anyone have a solution to use different versions of  SQL server and the Entity Framework within a single web application?

Comment: One item of importance to mention is that I am in the middle of a migration from sql 2000 to sql 2008 and have changed the connection strings and performed an "Update Model From Database" oddly enough if I modify all of the SSDL to use ProviderManifestToken = "2005" the app works.

Comment: I'm looking for an answer to this problem too. The only relevant google results I've found so far don't go into any depth.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I was able to accomplish this by putting each `edmx` in a separate assembly. Then in the connection string, replace all the `res://*/...` with `res://NameOfAssembly/...`

I can even perform joins between the two entity models (contrary to claims I found in other sources), e.g.:

```
var oneDb = new Entities2000();
var otherDb = new Entities2005();

var results = from one in oneDb.SomeSet
              join other in otherDb.OtherSet
                  on one.Property equals other.Property
              select new { 
                  SomeProp = one.SomeProp,
                  OtherProp = other.OtherProp 
              };
```

Comment: I see where this would work. The issue I was looking at was why was it not working in my environment. The only work around at the time was to set all ProviderManifestToken to the same version. Since this time I have migrated all dbs to MSSQL 2008. So why this may not answer my original question, it is an acceptable workaround.

Comment: I had same issue. Then I implemented all described in '@Cogwheel - Matthew Orlando' suggestion and it works perfect for both sql servers 2005 and 2008. Note: I had made a new project for data access to SQL 2008 with diff name and then copied all content from first and fixed 'ProviderManifestToken' for corresponding sql version and then replaced namespaces in second project - according to new assembly name ( don't know if it was necessary ). And now I'm happy.

Comment: +1 This worked for me when loading a edmx for SQL Server and one for Sybase SQL Anywhere from different assemblies

Comment: +1 I had an Oracle edmx and a Sql Server edmx, so this gave me a hint to try putting each edmx in its own project (e.g. App.OracleModel & App.SqlServerModel), now everything works. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

This link helped me to solve the problem when there was a difference in SQL server 2005 and 2008.
http://kkryczka.wordpress.com/2011/01/03/all-ssdl-artifacts-must-target-the-same-provider-the-providermanifesttoken-2008-is-different-from-2005-that-was-encountered-earlier/

Right click on the .edmx file and select Open with XML Editor.
Open Entity Framework .edmx file:

Change the ProviderManifestToken to 2008:

Looks like its a known issue for Microsoft.

Comment: Thanks man. I really struggled with this one. Another developer kept adding to our project with a different providermanifest. Good article

Comment: What I found in my case was, we had 3 projects in one solution, and we have changed the ProviderManifestToken in one of the project A, and this didnt let me to run even project B from the same solution.

Comment: In my case I had to change 2008 tot 2012 and at the bottom of the file you find :  <DesignerProperty Name="UseLegacyProvider" Value="True" />. 
Change that to False and it worked.